# Remove part of Expression

Tags: c#, .net, expression-trees

I have a generic method:

```
public void ExpressionBuilder<T>() where T: IEntity
{
   Expression<Func<T, long>> expr = e => e.Id; //Id is part of IEntity
   ...
}
```

The resulted expression contains casting of T to IEntity: e => Convert(e).Id
I want to remove this casting (to make it possible for EF to generate SQL). In other words I would like to replace Convert(e) by e.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we assume a `public long Id {get;}` on `T`, and the expression is that simple, then maybe just build it manually:

```
var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof (T), "e");
var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, long>>(
          Expression.PropertyOrField(param,"Id"), param);
```

A visitor should work for more complex examples; for example:

```
internal class FlattenInterface<T> : ExpressionVisitor
{
    protected override Expression VisitMember(MemberExpression node)
    {
        if(node.Member.DeclaringType == typeof(T))
        {
            return Expression.MakeMemberAccess(
                node.Expression,
                node.Expression.Type.GetMember(node.Member.Name).Single());
        }
        return base.VisitMember(node);
    }
}
```

and

```
var direct = (Expression<Func<T, long>>)new FlattenInterface<IEntity>()
       .Visit(expr);
```

Comment: Manually building of Expression always works but... it is manual :) I like more strongly-typed expressions built by C# compiler.

Answer (score 0):

I have done it by `ExpressionVisitor`:

```
expr = ExpressionVisitor<UnaryExpression>.Visit(expr, p => return p.Operand);
```

`ExpressionVisitor<T>` is just an convenient wrapper for `ExpressionVisitor`.

If you know better ways - please post it.

Comment: Which `ExpressionVisitor<T>` is this? The framework `ExpressionVisitor` is non-generic (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expressionvisitor.aspx). Also - converting *all* unary expressions is a bad thing, surely... `-a` is unary, and it is quite important that you don't replace it with `a`

Comment: I use these extensions: http://chriscavanagh.wordpress.com/2007/11/04/linq-expression-visitor/

Comment: @ldsa - that pre-dates 4.0; personally, I would suggest using the BCL version. Apart from anything else, it'll work for the new node types added in 4.0

Comment: I've edited your answer to mark up the inline code, because otherwise, the `<T>` is invisible, and the sentence after the code sample didn't make sense (reading "ExpressionVisitor is just an convenient wrapper for ExpressionVisitor.")